# ESP8266: "No space left on device" error when building nodemcu firmware

Tags: docker, windows-10, nodemcu

I am trying build the nodemcu firmware with a docker on a windows 10 system.

When I try to build the nodemcu firmware, I have this error:

```
(...)
PRUNE libmain.a libc.a
/opt:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/nodemcu-firmware/tools/toolchains/esp8266-linux-x86_64-20190731.0/bin
xtensa-lx106-elf-ar: /opt/nodemcu-firmware/sdk/esp_iot_sdk_v3.0-e4434aa/lib/libc.a: No space left on device
Makefile:334: recipe for target '/opt/nodemcu-firmware/sdk/.pruned-3.0-e4434aa' failed
make: *** [/opt/nodemcu-firmware/sdk/.pruned-3.0-e4434aa] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/opt/nodemcu-firmware'
```

I tried `docker system prune` but this error persists.

I tried execute `docker info` but doesn't help me:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 12
 Server Version: 19.03.1
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.14.131-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 3.419GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: RCEX:VYON:IG6T:AXCF:CSLX:3NVK:V453:DTSP:HW4Y:EKBY:PCVW:2UOJ
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 28
  Goroutines: 44
  System Time: 2020-12-21T02:04:22.387341144Z
  EventsListeners: 1
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

When I execute `docker system df`, I have this result:

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              4                   1                   673.8MB             209.8MB (31%)
Containers          1                   0                   0B                  0B
Local Volumes       10                  0                   0B                  0B
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

I am new in docker and I don't know what do to from here. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Docker tends to need cleanup after you work with it sometimes. There may be previous resources that were created in the past that are no longer in use, this is especially true if you are making use of volumes.
Sometimes, images are not fully created and end up becoming untagged dangling images which for the most part are undesirable. So you have to remove these undesirables that consume space.

1. `docker image prune`

> docker image prune removes all dangling images.
> 2. `docker volume prune`
> docker volume prune removes all 'volumes' which are not attached to any containers. These should always be ran before pruning containers otherwise all containers will get deleted this is because pruning containers removes all containers which are not running at the time the command is ran. For the most part in my experience volumes is often what consumes the most amount of resources in terms of space.

3. `docker container prune`

> For the most part this is optional and you can choose to do this or not

Now even after deleting dangling images there might still be other images that do not get deleted but you no longer need, like for example if you had older versions of the ***redis image*** and later download the most recent version of it, you may need to remove the older one if you no longer use it. You will have to delete this manually. Use the following commands:

```
docker image ls
docker rmi <image id>
```

The first command gives you a list of all the images you have downloaded, and the second command deletes it. sometimes you may have to use the `-f` flag on the delete command to force the deletion of an image:

```
docker rmi -f <image id>
```